# TYPO3 Backend with reverseProxyIP and ssl

Tags: typo3

My server configuration is a TYPO3 installation Vs. 6.2.31 combined with a reverse proxy. The system is running fine with http.

When we try to switch to https we geht this Error Message in the backend:

"Connection Problem
Sorry, but an error occurred while connecting to the server. Please check your network connection."

And the page tree is not loading.

When switching back to http all is working one again.

Our settings:

- [SYS][reverseProxyIP] = (IP of our reverse Proxy)
- [SYS][reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue] = last
- [SYS][reverseProxySSL] = *

What i tried:

- deactivate all extensions apart from the system extensions
- no entry in syslog (error reporting is on development)
- no entries in the server logs
- lockSSL in install tool 3 results in never ending 302 redirects
- lockSSL with option 2 results in this error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'TYPO3 Backend not accessed via SSL: TYPO3 Backend is configured to only be accessible through SSL. Change the URL in your browser and try again.' in /srv/httpd/sites/fland_ww1/typo3_src-6.2.31/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php:897 Stack trace: #0 /srv/httpd/sites/fland_ww1/typo3_src-6.2.31/typo3/init.php(54): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap->checkSslBackendAndRedirectIfNeeded() #1 /srv/httpd/sites/fland_ww1/typo3_src-6.2.31/typo3/index.php(21): require('/srv/httpd/site...') #2 {main} thrown in /srv/httpd/sites/fland_ww1/typo3_src-6.2.31/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php on line 897

It seems that some requests e.g. for the page tree are made without ssl - ajax calls i presume - but i dont have a clue how to debug it.

Andy ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: We found a hint in browser protocols: the ajax call ajax.php?ajaxID=ExtDirect:route&namespace=TYPO3.Components.PageTree is blocked because of mixed content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread is quite old, but because many people do read until now i will try an answer. We could solve the problem (and once again in a different installation) with the following settings:

- [SYS][reverseProxyIP] = (IP of our reverse Proxy)
- [SYS][reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue] = firt
- [SYS][reverseProxySSL] = *

AND - that is important - changes in the server config too:

- RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
- SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
- SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1

I assume it was the first:

- RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

So in the end the problem was in the server config.

Comment: If this not work, set [SYS][reverseProxyIP] = '*'.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same version at a customer and with a load balancer / proxy.

The only difference is `[SYS][reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue] = first`.
Also, `[BE][lockSSL] = 1` is set.

Maybe it helps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But same effect. With lockSSL=1 i get the same error message as with lockSSL=2 oder 3 - see above.

Comment: Then I would suggest to check the configuration of the proxy.